# SonarQube. Detect cases of overriding methods which is annotated with the certain annotation in superclass. (this external API)

Tags: java, sonarqube

Now I'm trying to implement custom rule usin SonarQube for the next case. For example I have next class:

```
public class SuperClass{
   @CannotOverrideAnnotation
   protected void methodCanNotBeOverrided(){}
   protected void methodCanBeOverrided(){}
}
```

And I'd like to detect cases where somebody tries to override methodCanNotBeOverrided.

```
public class ChildClass extend SuperClass{
  protected void methodCanNotBeOverrided(){} // Noncompliant
  protected void methodCanBeOverrided(){}  //Compliant
}
```

Firstable, I think I have to visit every MethodTree and get owner of it like as:

```
@Override
protected void visitNode(MethodTree method){
    Tree declaration = method.symbol().owner().declaration();
    if (declaration.is(Tree.Kind.CLASS)) {
        TypeTree superClass = ((ClassTree) declaration).superClass();
    }
}
```

<strike>Ok, I've got superClass and I can extract fullyQualifiedName and use Reflection API.... but maybe there is other way to do it via SonarQube API?</strike>
I've found out that RetentionPolicy for this annotations equals to SOURCE, it means that I have no idea now how to implement rule, Reflection API cannot help me... Could anybody help me with ideas about this stuff.

Also I've found out that there is a very useful method in `JavaSymbol.MethodJavaSymbol` such as `overriddenSymbol` but this class doesn't belong org.sonar.plugins.java.api package and according to [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/CF8d1y35m20) I cannot use it. 
org.sonar.plugins.java.api package containts the similar interface Symbol, but there is only common methods for all languages and there're not specific methods for Java.

I will be great for any help.

P.s. I'd like to emphasize that SuperClass - is an external library. I don't have an opportunity to change something there.

Comment: It makes no sense for me to do that using Sonar. Java has the feature to mark methods `final` to avoid overriding, so what's the issue with using that?

Comment: @Tom Yep, I know that we can use `final`, but now I'm speaking about external API and this link cannot help me, unfortunately

Comment: If it is an external API, then how can you add that annotation to it?

Comment: @Tom this annotation was placed by developer of this API already.

Comment: @Tom generally speaking can we get super-method's annotation in Sonar?

Comment: From the api this is not possible today. You could check if the super method is annotated but only if the annotation is available in the bytecode which : given the Source retention policy is not the case. So I tend to think this is a dead end.